# How can I enter a passphrase in command line using git?

Tags: ssh, git, passphrase

I am using git in my development environment.

When I run the command `git pull origin master` is there any way to pass the 
passphrase from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You should be [using an agent](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc2/) for this so that you only need enter your passphrase once.

Comment: I followed the link and included the password in my ssh agent.
Now, I am able to run the command "git pull origin master" and I am able to update my code base. The problem is if my put that command in 
a shell script and try to execute the script I am getting the following error.

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

My Shell script contains the following lines

su nanda -c "cd /var/www/vhosts/apps.mydomains.com/subdomains/nanda/httpdocs/ib_test; git pull origin master"

Is anything I am missing here ?

Comment: @Supratik: Access to an agent is restricted to the user that started the agent (via permissions on the named socket in the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable). The pull running as `nanda` can not access your agent. You might be able to use the referenced `keychain` script (which has since moved to [funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/en/security/keychain/intro/) and [github](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain)) to maintain an agent for your `nanda` user. Or, pull under your user and let `nada` access a local “clone” repository, or maybe give `nanda` an unencrypted key (ick) that can access *origin*.